# Best DB structure for large CSVs?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have previously posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32923338/246260), however, I have been directed here.

I'm getting to the stage where I need to analyse lots of flat CSVs:

- Read-in around 500GB of CSVs (e.g. daily data split by month)
- Group the data (e.g. by month or year)
- Output the aggregated data as a small CSV

I wasn't sure whether sqlite was the right package for this (adding CSVs to it appears to take a long time and as in my link above after a certain size I can't access the database) and whether I should consider something else like PostgreSQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

I'm looking to invest in a hardware/software platform for this (e.g. SSD, RAID, Microsoft SQL Server) and was hoping for some information on where to begin.

Particularly, if PostgreSQL is a possibility - is there a similar way to quickly import CSVs like here:

https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/

**Edit (08/10/15):**

I'm testing out uploading the data into a PostgreSQL database and am averaging 16 minutes per 10GB CSV. My issue is that some of my columns are very big so I would have to change them from bigint to varchar, etc. The data has 38 columns and around 50 mill rows per file so figuring out which categorical variables are strings or integers is a real pain.

At the moment I am using:
`cur.copy_expert(sql="COPY %s FROM stdin DELIMITERS '~' CSV;", file=f)`, **with my data-type mainly being varchar**. I did this because the CSV is a bit messy and sometimes what I think is an integer turns out be alphanumeric and I have to re-upload.

Would it be much slower to import as a Pandas data-frame (so that panda takes care of column-type for me) and use that with sqlachemy to insert into Postgres? I'm guessing if PANDAs is a bit slower it will make up for it because the column types will be optimised (since it will decide on that for me).

E.g. something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mypath.csv')

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname')

df.to_sql("table", engine)
```

My main goal is to optimise this for the group-by command.

**Second Edit:**

Ahh, I guess best thing is to upload one CSV file using PANDAS and then copy the table structure into a new table which is then filled with the faster COPY command?

Comment: It's completely feasible with PostgreSQL (and, of course, with SQL Server, but that would cost you more, AFAIK).  It's hard to tell what sort of HW you need for it, but you can already test it (possibly with a smaller dataset) on an average notebook, too.  If you have to do aggregates over the whole dataset, having a big amount of RAM and many smaller disks (SSDs) connected to a decent RAID controller will be definitely needed (or time - if you can wait for the results, it's always cheaper).

Comment: Dezso, thank you for the comment.  Thank-you llia for the question.  I wanted to do the same thing with PostgreSQL myself.  Definitely would be cheaper with Postgres.  I've worked with SQL-Server for many years doing BIDs, but would like an opensource solution to do this.  If you have the bandwidth, I would like to read how you did it in Postgres.   Best WIshes.  Keep us updated.

Comment: The corresponding built-in tool to `bcp` is `copy`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html (which processes text file located on the **server**). Another alternative is pgloader: http://pgloader.io/

Comment: You could use PowerShell to step over the CSV's and aggregate the data that way.  That's assuming you don't need to keep the source data around  for additional analysis later. No need for a database at all that way.

Comment: @JonathanFite I don't know anything relevant about PowerShell - how well do you expect it to perform on a 500 GB dataset?

Comment: @dezso.  He said there are 500GB of CSV files, but they are daily, split by month.  I took that to assume that there was a CSV file for each day, the sum total of which is 500GB of data.  So each specific CSV is not 500GB.            PowerShell --> Open daily CSV --> Total data, add to previous value for that specific month/year aggregate --> open next daily csv.  Should be fairly fast.  But as I said, does not lend itself to further analysis and is brute force.  But it sounds like this is a one time thing.

Comment: @JonathanFite ah, yes, updating the aggregates could work.  Let's see what they really want.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I probably wouldn't use a database in the first place.  It doesn't sound like you have any need for [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), which is one the main things which databases provide and which doesn't come cheap in terms of performance.  Nor does it sound like you need complicated indexes.

What I would do (and have done, an awful lot) is just loop over the files with Perl or Python and use their built-in hash table features to generate your aggregates.  Since you have specified that the output is small, you should have little problem holding the intermediate aggregation state in memory for the duration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is what I ended up doing -> since the data wasn't linked I was able to load each 10GB file into RAM collapse and repeat. However, I was hoping for a more robust solution (for the future) if for instance: (a) I can't load the individual files into RAM because they are 20GB, (b) I would need to perform joins or any other operation which involves the data being joined. Which is why I though it would be nicer to have all the data in full sitting in a database which I can then cut-up / collapse / join / etc.

Comment: Perl works very well for streaming files, you don't have to (and usually should not) read it all into RAM.  If you do want to load it to database, `PostgreSQL` has the COPY command which can read csv files.  You have to careful around how NULLs are handled, and how escapes and embedded newlines are handled (there is not a single CSV specification which defines these things, so you can find quirks in various data sets).

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing out uploading the data into a PostgreSQL database and am averaging 16 minutes per 10GB CSV. My issue is that some of my columns are very big so I would have to change them from bigint to varchar, etc. At the moment I am using "COPY %s FROM stdin DELIMITERS '~' CSV;" with my data-type mainly being varchar. Would it be much sloer to import as Pandas data-frame and use that with sqlachemy to insert into Postgres? I'm guessing if PANDAs is a bit slower it will make up for it because the column types will be optimised. My main goal is to optimise this for the group-by command.

Comment: Sorry, I don't anything about Panda or sqlalchemy.  I would think sqlalchemy, just based on the name, should be able hook into the postgresql COPY method

Answer (score 0):

Use a data integration (ETL) **tool** like [Pentaho Data Integration (PDI)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/5.4/).  You can either do everything within PDI or upload it to Postgres for additional processing. PDI is free, open source, and I use it daily.

Aggregating is a common process associated w/ ETL tools, typically transforming data to a higher grain for additional processing.  Which is sounds like what you're doing. Plus, this tool will allow you to develop quickly and handle errors more readily.

In situations like these, there is no reason to write code!

[This show the csv input step.](https://youtu.be/1XB6mpXCgi4)

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to the all help -> I was able to painlessly create a postgreSQL database quite easily using the below code.

However, it hasn't really helped **because it still takes days and days to perform the group by.**

I'm not really sure of a faster way of doing this; would creating 20 indexes first help? It seems the fastest way to collapse is to keep the data in its disaggregated form.

```
def call_robocopy(from_folder='',
                  to_folder='',
                  my_log='H:/robocopy_log.txt'):
    """
    Copy files to working directory
    robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]
    """
    if os.path.isdir(from_folder) & \
            os.path.isdir(to_folder):
        call(["robocopy", from_folder, to_folder, "/LOG:%s" % my_log])
    else:
        print("Paths not entered correctly")

def pandas_temp_table(path_2_csv='',
                      tmp_table='',):
    """
    Upload data to a temporary table first using PANDAs to identify optimal data-types for columns
    PANDAS is not speed-efficient as it uses INSERT commands rather than COPY e.g. it took COPY 16mins average
    to get a 15GB CSV into the database (door-to-door) whereas pandas.to_sql took 50mins
    """
    # Pandas can use sqlalchemy engine
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://%s:%s@localhost:5432/%s' %(myusername, mypassword, mydatabase))
    if engine:
        print('Connected: %s' % engine)
    else:
        print('Connection lost')
        sys.exit(1)

    tmp_table += '_temp'
    counter = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in os.listdir(path_2_csv):
        # Cycle through all CSVs and upload a small chunk to make sure everything is OK
        if counter < 1:
            if i.endswith(".csv") & i.startswith("100_pct"):
                print("Reading CSV: %s into PANDAs data-frame" % i)

                # First 1,000,000 rows
                #df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_2_csv, i), nrows=1000000, header=None, sep='~') #sep=None; automatically find by sniffing

                # Upload whole file
                df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_2_csv, i), header=None, sep='~') #sep=None; automatically find by sniffing
                df.columns = [
                           .. around 30 columns ..
                        ]
                print("CSV read-in successfully")
                print(df.shape)
                print("Uploading %s to SQL Table: %s" % (i, tmp_table))
                df.to_sql(tmp_table, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
                counter += 1
                current_speed = ((time.time()-start_time)/60)/counter
                print("Average speed is %.2f minutes per database" % current_speed)
                print("Successfully uploaded: %d" % counter)

    end_time = time.time()
    print("Total duration of INSERT: %.2f minutes" % (end_time - start_time)/60)

def create_postgresql_table(my_table=''):
    """
    Create table copying the structure of the temp table created using pandas
    Timer to benchmark
    """
    # Connect
    con = psycopg2.connect(database=mydatabase, user=myusername, password=mypassword)
    cur = con.cursor()
    if con:
        print('Connected: %s' % con)
    else:
        print('Connection lost')
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        # Check if table exists already
        cur.execute("""
                    SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = '{0}';
                    """.format(my_table))
        table_test = cur.fetchone()[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print('Table %s does not exist' % my_table)
        table_test = None

    if table_test:
        print('%s already exists' % mytable)
    else:
        print('Creating table: %s' % mytable)
        try:
            # Copy structure and no data (1=2 is false)
            cur.execute("""
                        CREATE TABLE {0} AS SELECT * FROM {1} WHERE 1=2;
                        """.format(my_table, my_table+'_temp'))
            con.commit()
            print('Table created successfully')
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
            if con:
                con.rollback()
            print('Error %s' % e)
            sys.exit(1)
    con.close()


def copy_csv_to_table(path_2_csv='',
                      my_table=''):
    """
    Use the PostgreSQL COPY command to bulk-copy the CSVs into the newly created table
    """
    # Connect
    con = psycopg2.connect(database=mydatabase, user=myusername, password=mypassword)
    cur = con.cursor()
    if con:
        print('Connected: %s' % con)
    else:
        print('Connection lost')
        sys.exit(1)

    copy_sql = """
               COPY %s FROM stdin DELIMITERS '~' CSV;
               """ % my_table
    counter = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in os.listdir(path_2_csv):
        if i.endswith(".csv") & i.startswith("100_pct"):
            print("Uploading %s to %s" % (i, mytable))
            with open(os.path.join(path_2_csv, i), 'r') as f:
                cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
                con.commit()
                counter += 1
                print("Successfully uploaded %d CSVs" % counter)
                current_speed = ((time.time()-start_time)/60)/counter
                print("Average speed is %.2f minutes per database" % current_speed)
    con.close()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Total duration of COPY: %.2f minutes" % (end_time - start_time)/60)


def sql_query_to_csv(my_table='',
                     csv_out=''):
    """
    Submit query to created PostgreSQL database and output results to a CSV
    """
    # Connect
    con = psycopg2.connect(database=mydatabase, user=myusername, password=mypassword)
    cur = con.cursor()
    if con:
        print('Connected: %s' % con)
    else:
        print('Connection lost')
        sys.exit(1)

    start_time = time.time()
    my_query = """
                SELECT
                    SUM("A"),
                    SUM("B"),
                    SUM("C"),
                    COUNT(1) AS "D",
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "PURCHASE_DATE"::text::date) AS "YEAR",
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "PURCHASE_DATE"::text::date) AS "MONTH",
                    .. 20 more columns ...
                FROM {0}
                GROUP BY
         .. 20 columns ...
                """.format(my_table)
    start_time = time.time()
    output_query = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(my_query)
    with open(csv_out, 'w') as f:
        cur.copy_expert(output_query, f)
        print("Successfully submitted results to: %s" % csv_out)
    con.close()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Total duration of Query: %.2f minutes" % (end_time - start_time)/60)
```